# Is there an Advantage to Shared Memory in a Multithreaded Program?

Tags: c, multithreading, posix, shared-memory

Hey I have a multithreaded program i wrote that shares memory between the threads, would there be some way to make it more efficient by using shared memory instead of regular memory from malloc?

Also if there are ways i can improve this program it's listed on github [here](https://github.com/DavidAwad/ProducerComsumer).

also, YES i know there are rampant memory leaks, do these affect the speed of the program?

Comment: This question is based on a misunderstanding, but I don't think it merits all the downvotes and close votes it's gotten. It's still a valid question and an answer explaining the misunderstanding and correcting it is appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Shared Memory* usually refers to memory shared between different processes and needs special OS calls to set up and use: `shm_open` for POSIX shared memory, `shmget` for SysV shared memory or `mmap` with the `MAP_SHARED` flag.

Threads within the same process can simply access the process' memory (the one you get from `malloc`).

Since Shared Memory has overhead that's unnecessary for a normal multi-threaded program, you do not gain any benefit by using it in a single-process program.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I'm saying.